# VideoJS live streaming HLS does not start from last segment

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, video.js

I'm using videojs to play a live streaming event in HLS.

Problem is that on desktop I got the last few segments, on android (with google chrome) live streaming start from first second every time.

There is a way to specify to videojs to set the progress-bar to the last second available?
I can't get the total duration (at start) from videojs so i can't set currentTime properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `overrideNative` option. Basically Video.js currently defers to a browser's native HLS support if it has it, but Android's native HLS isn't very good.

https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming#overridenative